# (Arch Linux) Ошибка: Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok

Tags: linux, archlinux, bios

Когда я загружаюсь с Флешки, чтобы установить **Arch Linux** на отформатированный ssd, нажимаю `Arch Linux install medium (x86_64, BIOS)`, после появляется консоль, затем эта ошибка: `Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok` Дальше она пропадает, и можно устанавливать Arch. Эта ошибка не мешает установки дистрибутива. В BIOS сбрасывал настройки на default. У меня возникло предположение, что это связано с ACPI. Также пишут, что проблема появляется из-за старых драйверов на BIOS. Я попробовал вписать параметры загрузки через Tab: `edd=off`. Ошибки нет, однако при повторной загрузке без этого параметра она снова появляется. С чем эта ошибка связана и как ее можно убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> С чем эта ошибка связана

вариантов может быть много, можно попробовать узнать на чем оно спотыкается, для этого добавив в параметры ядра `loglevel=7` (подглядел [здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Preboot_Execution_Environment#VirtualBox_cannot_boot_while_real_machines_can))

> и как ее можно убрать?

ну, если параметр ядра `edd=off` вам помогает то просто добавьте его на постоянной основе в ваш **загрузчик** ядра, подробнее смотри [Kernel_parameters](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Kernel_parameters#Configuration) на арчвики.

п.с.

общая инфа с офсайта по всем доступным параметрам ядра ~ [kernel-parameters](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)

Comment: Я понял, почему это ошибка вызвала именно edd=off. У меня материнская плата Asus P9D-X (уже старая для нынешнего времени) поэтому, скорее всего, реализации BIOS Enhanced Disk Drive  **нет**  _This option is experimental and is known to fail to boot on some obscure configurations. Most disk controller BIOS vendors do not yet implement this feature_ https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/EDD.html